# GetSubKeysNames() returns null using Remote Registry - WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registry

In my Programm i am trying to get a List of SIDs from all users using the Remote Registry of a server. They are located in LocalMachine:

```
\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Here is my code:

```
public void ReadRegKeys(string machineName)
    {
        RegistryKey rk = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, machineName);
        rk.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList");
        string[] regKeys = rk.GetSubKeyNames();

        foreach(string item in regKeys) {
            //Do something
    }
```

My Problem is that the Array doesnt contain the Names/Keys.. I dont receive an error and the Array stays Empty. After that I tried to read the SubKeys of HKEY_Users and it was successfull. All the Sub Keys were saved in the Array correctly.

Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found the solution.. Had to add `RegistryView.Registry64` at the end of the `OpenRemoteBaseKey()` method.